# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to select the table, but it show

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

My code:

```
<?php
require 'database/db.php';
$fetch = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM buyhistory WHERE email = xxx@hotmail.com ORDER BY user_id DESC ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['purchasedate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['buyitem'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['enddate'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: how to fix it? thanks

Comment: By fixing whatever's wrong with your SQL query.  You might start by enclosing string values in quotes.  It's also a good idea to actually check for errors after executing a SQL query, since you're obviously getting an error and ignoring it here.

Answer (score 0):

should be email='xxx@hotmail.com'

```
$fetch = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM buyhistory WHERE email = 'xxx@hotmail.com' ORDER BY user_id DESC");
```